# Tkinter GUI with websocket server

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, websocket, python-asyncio

I created a simple websocket class server
import websockets
import asyncio
import threading

class OcppServer():

```
def __init__(self):
    self.active_connections = []
    self.message_queue = asyncio.Queue()

async def callback(self, websocket, path):
    if websocket not in self.active_connections:
        self.active_connections.append(websocket)

    async for message in websocket:
        print(message)
        await self.message_queue.put(message)

async def start_server(self):
    async with websockets.serve(self.callback, IP, PORT):
        await asyncio.Future()

def run_server(self):
    asyncio.run(self.start_server())

def start_server_thread(self):
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run_server)
    server_thread.start()
```

I also created a tkinter gui:

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import asyncio
import time
from datetime import datetime
from ocpp_module.ocpp_serv import OcppServer


class MessageApp:
    def __init__(self, root, window_width=1500, window_height=1000):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Message Selector with Server Response")
        self.root.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}")
        self.server = OcppServer()

        self.right_frame = tk.Frame(self.root, borderwidth=2, relief="solid")
        self.right_frame.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.right_frame)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

        self.text_widget_server = tk.Text(self.right_frame, wrap=tk.WORD, width=70, height=45,
                                          yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        self.text_widget_server.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        self.text_widget_server.pack()

        self.scrollbar.config(command=self.text_widget_server.yview)
       
    async def update_display(self):
        while True:
            response = await self.server.message_queue.get()
            print("rsponse:" + str(response))

            self.update_textbox(response)

    @staticmethod
    def get_current_time_utc():
        return datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")


    def update_textbox(self, response):
        self.text_widget_server.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
        self.text_widget_server.insert(tk.END, "SEND>>> " + response + '\n')
        self.text_widget_server.config(state=tk.DISABLED)

    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MessageApp(root)
    app.server.start_server_thread()
    root.mainloop()
```

The problem is I have no idea how to connect server with gui. How to print every message received from a server on a tkinter TextBox? Also I want to implement a possibility to send messages later. I tried something with Asyncio Queue but I think the problem might be in a created thread.